# Deploying flask on heroku with gunicorn gives R12 timeout issues

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

Digging around online gives me some clue as to the fact that maybe heroku is having some-time out issues for some of the build. However another suggestion was to explicitly parametrize the port, however I seem to still get this issue. The localhost version works well.

```
   stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2016-02-22T22:36:36.687853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-22 22:36:36 +0000] [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
    2016-02-22T22:36:42.845739+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn login:app -b 0.0.0.0:7032 --timeout 90`
    2016-02-22T22:36:45.089125+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-22 22:36:45 +0000] [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:7032 (3)
    2016-02-22T22:36:45.089254+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-22 22:36:45 +0000] [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
    2016-02-22T22:36:45.088398+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-22 22:36:45 +0000] [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.3.0
    2016-02-22T22:36:45.166359+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-22 22:36:45 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
    2016-02-22T22:36:45.093125+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-02-22 22:36:45 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
    2016-02-22T22:36:46.242345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
    2016-02-22T22:36:46.242463+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
    2016-02-22T22:36:46.460542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2016-02-22T22:36:47.319021+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

Here is the `Procfile`

```
web: gunicorn login:app -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT --timeout 90
```

and here is the `__main__`of `login.py`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
  app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

The question is, is the app configuration correct. What else can I do to elucidate this issue. I don't seem to get any more granularity with this error.

Here is my `requirements.txt`

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.11.4
argparse==1.2.1
itsdangerous==0.24
mongoengine==0.8.7
pymongo==2.9.2
requests==2.9.1
gunicorn==19.3.0
```

My includes are:

```
import sys, os, re, hashlib, logging, urllib
import hashlib, base64, uuid, datetime, json, requests
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from flask import render_template
from database import mongo
from random import shuffle
from datetime import timedelta
```

What can I realistically do to elucidate this issue - I have no idea what component is misbehaving and causing an issue. How could I get clearer more specific error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, it was a version issue with the import of urlencode

It was solved:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urlencode
except ImportError:
    from urllib import urlencode
```

But I only could discover this  message after install NewRelic - which is actually a pretty awesome tool!